# return specific part of url preg_match

Tags: php, regex

Imagine you have this cases

```
$d='http://www.example.com/';
$d1='http://example.com/';
$d2='http://www.example.com';
$d3='www.example.com/';
$d4='http://www.example.com/';
$d5='http://www.example.com/blabla/blabla.php';
```

I need to get only **example.com** and nothing else.
I've tried using **parse_url** to no avail.

Using `parse_url($d1, PHP_URL_HOST);` returns nothing in $d3, for example.

Can any of you provide a ereg to match this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It is `PHP_URL_HOST` for [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url).

Comment: @BoltClock, can we upvote an edit?

Comment: Re edited the question, it's parse_url not path_url.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `path_url` function, but you can use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) function to get the host (domain name) out of a URL string:

```
if(!preg_match('#^https?://#', $str))
{
    $domain = 'http://' . $domain;
}

$domain = parse_url($str, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's parse_url, of course. My bad.
In $d3 for example it returns nothing. So I guess i should come up with a better approach.

Comment: @NicolásTorres:  See my updated answer.  The code will prepend **http://** to the string if it is not present.